# angularjs ng-repeat list not updated when element is added/removed

Tags: angularjs

There is a list of users retrieved from a rest api. Here is the template

```
<div ng:controller="UserController">
    <a ng-click="createUser()">Create User</a>

    <div ng-view>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users">
                 {[{user.first_name}]} {[{user.last_name}]} 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The JS:

```
function UserController($scope, User, Group){
    $scope.users = User.query();

    $scope.createUser = function(){

        //$scope.users = null;
        //$scope.users.pop();
        //$scope.users.push(new User({id:'5'}));

        console.log($scope.users);
    }
}
```

The service: http://dpaste.com/1065440/

All users a retrieved and listed correctly. The problem is that I cannot manipulate the rendered list at all. No matter what I do push, pop or set to null. The list does not change in the template. However the last log statement shows the changes, it prints e.g. NULL when the users array is set to null.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Where are you calling createUser()?  You'll probably need to add a callback function to query(), then call createUser() inside the callback.

Comment: Sorry I missed that button. I edited my question.

Comment: Check my answer, I edited in light of the new information you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object you push into the array should be an instance of `User`

```
function UserController($scope, User){

    $scope.users = User.query();

    $scope.createUser = function(){
        $scope.users.push(new User({first_name:'Bob', last_name: 'Schmitt'}));
    }   
}
```

So, use `new User({})`

From our conversation, it seems the problem was in the routing. The same outer controller was assigned to the partial that was being loaded in the `ng-view`. Removing `ng:controller="UserController"` and moving the `createUser` button to the partial would solve the problem, but if there's really a need to call the `createUser` method from outside of `ng-view`, then all the data related to it will need to be in the outer controller. So, you can keep your outer controller as it is, and change your route to use an empty placeholder controller.

Comment: What is the effect of new User? Does this make an api call? I tried your suggestion but it still does not work.

Comment: It makes the object you'll push into the array an instance of User, which makes it inherit all the instance methods such as $save etc. In short: attaches the User behavior to it.

Comment: Yes see my update. Users holds one user fetched from rest api. This user is rendered however the new user is not rendered.

Comment: I just testet, when I dublicate the user comming from rest api and push the duplicated object onto the users array, nothing happens as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28540/discussion-between-artworkad--and-finishingmove)

Answer (score 3):

make sure createUser is being called. IE ng-click or something.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="createUser()">Create User</button>
```

Your push function looks correct, but your binding in html looks wrong. It should be double curly brackets.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
</li>
```

Added Example I've used previously on adding object.

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="add()" >Add</button>
        <div id="container">
            <div ng-repeat="test in tests>{{test.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$scope.tests = {};

$scope.add = function() {
   var newTest = {name: 'Test Message'};

   $scope.tests.push(newTest);
};
```

Comment: I missed that info, I use custom curly and I just missed that button. Will be correct next time.

Comment: Ahh, I don't see an issue then, have you set break points inside your createUser function to see if it's hit, then try printing out the User object on screen to debug. {{users}}